# Ĉu "mi ekzercas mian Esperanton" estas evitinda esprimo?

Tags: word-usage

Mi kelkfoje legas *mi ekzercas mian Francan/Hispanan/ktp*. Mi kredas ke tia frazo povas deveni de la Angla frazo *I practice my Spanish*. Ĉu la frazo *Mi ekzercas mian Xn* (kie 'X' estas nomo de lingvo) estas sufiĉe kutima/klara/Esperanteca por esti uzinda?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tiuj frazoj ne estas ĝustaj. Laŭ PIV la difino de "ekzerci" estas "Lertigi per ripetata praktikado" (mi diras ke ĝi estas simila al la angla "to train"), do ĝia objekto devas esti tiu/tio, kiu/kio fariĝas lerta pro tiu ripetata praktikado. "Esperanto" ne povas fariĝi lerta, ĉar ĝi ne estas estaĵo, kiu povas agi lerte. Ekzemploj:

- Mi ekzercas min en Esperanto (*Mi* fariĝas lerta en Esperanto)
- Li uzis ĉiun eblon por ekzerci sin pri la angla. (oni kelkfoje uzas "pri" aŭ "je" anstataŭ "en")
- Ĉu ni kunvenas por ekzerciĝi en esperanta parolado?
- Mi jam longe ne ekzercis min en tio.
- Ili daŭrigis interŝanĝi leterojn kun siaj korespondantoj, iomete legis kaj ekzercis sin per babilado.
- Ilo estas senutila por persono kiu ne scias uzi ĝin kaj neniam ekzercis sin je ĝi.
- Tiel mi povus mense ekzerci min, luktante kontraŭ — por anglalingvano — malfacila, ja arĥaikiĝinta lingvo.
- JELK eldonis ankaŭ japanlingvan esearon Kiel ekzerci sin en la konversacio de Esperanto.

[PIV mem diras](http://vortaro.net/#ekzerci): "Neĝuste estas uzi kiel objekton de ekzerci la temon de la ekzercado: oni ne «ekzercas sian piecon», sed «ekzercas sin al pieco»"

Answer (score 1):

Oni ne ekzercas lingvon sed ja eblas praktiki lingvon.

Jen ekzemploj:

- mi ne havis multajn profesiajn ŝancojn praktiki mian anglan.
- pli ol 20 partoprenantoj praktikis la lingvon je du niveloj
- oni serioze laboras kaj multe lernas, konstante praktikas la lingvon
- oni pritraktis movadajn aferojn k praktikis la lingvon
- Ekde tiam oni aranĝas ĉiusomere kunvenojn por praktiki la internacian lingvon
- por uzi kaj praktiki la Zamenhofan lingvon
- Entute 25 diversaĝaj lernejanoj dum unu semajno praktikis Esperanton
- li venis Ruslandon, ĉar volis praktiki Esperanton
- buŝe praktiki lingvon

Comment: Tio ne estas ĝusta: praktiki = "Efektive plenumi sian profesion" (angla ekzemplo: "to practice medicine")  kaj ekzerci = "Lertigi per ripetata praktikado", laŭ PIV.

Comment: La PIV-a difino de "praktiki" estas klare erara. Estas multege da ekzemploj de aliaj uzoj de "praktiki." Oni povas praktik magiajn artojn, virtojn, religion, kaj bonon. Mi aldonis multajn ekzemplojn el Tekstaro pri praktikado de lingvoj.

Comment: Oni ja povas "praktiki lingvon", tio signifas angle "put into praktice". Sed estas malĝuste diri ke oni ne povas "ekzerci sin en lingvo" aŭ "ekzerciĝi en lingvo". La signifoj de tiuj vortoj ne estas samaj, kaj estas ofta eraro diri "praktiki" kiam "ekzerci" pli taŭgus.

Comment: Eble ja estas erare diri ke oni ne povas "ekzerci sin en lingvo", sed mi ne diras tion. Mi ankaŭ neniel asertis ke "ekzerci" kaj "praktiki" estas sinonimaj.